# Copy data between tables considering foreign key relationship

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, ssms, azure-data-sync

I tried to use Export option from SSMS which gives an error saying failed due to foreign key relationship.

How to copy data between tables(more than 400+) of two different azure sql server with has the same schema? It's fine to truncate data before copying the data as it is a full load.

**Error:**

> TITLE: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard
>
> Error 0xc002f210: Preparation SQL Task 1: Executing the query "TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[table_name] "
> failed with the following error: "Cannot truncate table 'dbo.table_name'
> because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.". Possible
> failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set
> correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established
> correctly.

Comment: If this actually a full copy of the other database? Are there other objects in the target database that you need to retain? If not, why not use a bacpac?

Comment: @ThomA This is not a full copy of the other database, and I need to retain other objects which are out of target object. I have different schemas, out of which only tables belongs to a schema need to copied to another database. Even If I can get a suggestion for copying few tables irrespective schema is fine but it should consider the foreign key relation ship.

Comment: So what is the *actual* error you are getting here?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here. Why are you trying to `TRUNCATE` the tables? If you want to "reset" thing you would be better off `DROP`ing the objects and recreating them. You'll need to ensure you `DROP` them in the correct order thoughl you couldnt' `DROP` the `Customer` table, for example, before you `DROP` the `CustomerOrder` table if you have foreign key relationships.

Comment: @ThomA Dropping the tables can be an issue, the schema and constraints won't copied, right?

Comment: You would script those across too. As the error tells you, you can't `TRUNCATE` a table that has a foreign key. The alternative would be the `DROP` all your foreign keys, `TRUNCATE` all the tables, and then recreate them all.

Comment: @ThomA Ah I don't have those scripts :|

Comment: So you can't access the definitions of the tables? Then you're going to need to perform an "upsert" against all your tables to `DELETE` unmatched rows, `UPDATE` matched rows, and `INSERT` missing rows.

Comment: @ThomA Okay, Can you provide script as an answer? I can try with group of tables( like tables belongs to `Customer` as per your mention)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use SQL Data Sync to replicate data between the two tables. You could replicate the data in one-direction or bi-directional. You can create a sync group involving the tables and other related tables needed. You can use SQL Data Sync to copy the data one time and get an initial load of data or to keep the tables in sync. Frequency of the sync could be seonds, minutes, hours, days or manual.

You will have to regularly checking the sync group’s history log and ensure that all conflicts are resolved, and changes are successfully propagated throughout the sync group databases. For example, a sync group may fail to update a row with a value that violates a foreign key constraint. In that scenario, you can update the foreign key values to include the values contained in the failed rows or you update the data values in the failed row to be compatible with the schema or foreign keys in
the target database. After that the sync group will continue to replicate the data between the two tables.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-sql-server-configure?view=azuresql) you will find how to get started with SQL Data Sync.

Comment: SQL Data Sync option is not a right choice for our usecases, as we are having 400+ tables,  we need to manually select all the tables, there is no option to select specific schema. I heard that Azure SQL Data Sync is 32bit version and it's not fully matured yet. So, we may face some more unknow issues during the process :|

Comment: Azure SQL Data Sync was in Preview since 2011 It is on GA since 2018 https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-general-availability-of-azure-sql-data-sync/.  About the schema, I agree. I hope you find what you are looking for.